# value is not getting stored in "state" by " this.setState({ value})"

Tags: reactjs, jwt, setstate, react-state-management, react-state

I am getting "user" from "decoded token" and setting that user in state, but value is not getting store in state although "user" has a value.

Here is my code.

```
class Complainer extends Component {

  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {

    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    console.log(user);

    this.setState({ user });

    if (!user) window.location = '/';

  }
```

but user is not getting stored in state. please help.

Comment: this.state.user will give user in render method if output of auth.getCurrentUser is correct. Please provide more info.

Comment: can you update the render part in your code?

Comment: my root of the app is login page. when user logged in , system redirects the user to complainer page. then in ComponentDidMount() i get the user from my getCurrentUser() where i decode the token.

Comment: class Complainer extends Component {
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    console.log(user);
    this.setState({ user });
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <main className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/complainer/view-all" component={AllComplaints} />
             <Route path="/complainer/not-found" component={notfound} />
            <Showcase user={this.state.user} />
          </Switch>
          </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class Complainer extends Component
{
  state = {
    user: '',
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    console.log(user);
    this.setState({
      user: user
    });
  }

  render(){

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/complainer/view-all" component={AllComplaints} />
          <Route path="/complainer/not-found" component={notfound} />
          <Showcase user={this.state.user} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```